# Use Hooks in OneSignal

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I have a OneSignal implementation that returns an effect hook and is called in app's root.

- useOneSignal.ts:

```
const useOneSignal = () => {

  return useEffect(() => {
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(6, 0);

    OneSignal.init(ONESIGNAL.appID, {
      kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false,
      kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false,
    });

    OneSignal.addEventListener("received", onReceived.bind(this));
    OneSignal.addEventListener("opened", onOpened);

    OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2);
  }, []);
};
```

I have data in redux that contains URLs for every ID I could get in the notification. I want to use hooks to access data but React Native gives hook rules errors when I try it.

- hook.ts

```
export const useProject = (projectID: number): Project => {
    const projects = useSelector(selectProjectsAsDict);

    return projects[projectID];
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? The two hooks here don't have any connection between them... I guess the error is at the place where you use the hooks. They have to be called unconditionally in the same order at every render (so NOT in an `if`-clause or inside of a `useEffect` or something like this). Have you tried to use `eslint` with `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`? This provides very usefull feedback

Comment: I would recommend that you read the documentation for hooks: [Rule of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)